# Error when Scaffold-DbContext with ConnectionString from appsettings.json, but works if manually specifying same connection string

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, dbcontext, scaffold

I am trying to reverse create the C# code from an existing database.

If I manually enter my connection string and type the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False'    
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -Tables DeviceParameterWithDevice -Context DPWDContext  
         -OutputDir Models -Force
```

This works OK, and I get all the correct code produced.

I add the same connection string into the `appsettings.json` file (as well as the `appsettings.Development.json` file - just in case)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EnviroWatchDB": "Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

If I run

```
Scaffold-DbContext -connection name=EnviroWatchDB     
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -Tables DeviceParameterWithDevice -Context DPWDContext  
         -OutputDir Models
```

I get the following errors

> Unhandled exception. Unhandled exception. Unhandled exception.
> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
>
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CreateUri(String uri)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(String requestUri)
> at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<<$>b__1>d.MoveNext() in Z:\MyDir\Program.cs:line 111
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_1(Object state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CreateUri(String uri)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(String requestUri)
> at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<<$>b__1>d.MoveNext() in Z:\MyDirProgram.cs:line 111
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_1(Object state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

I have tried adding this to the `program.cs` file

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EnviroWatchDB");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

but no effect.

Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove from the json file what is after the single quotation mark.

Comment: try to simplify the connection string, use only db prams and not commands

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string in the `appsettings.json` is just simply invalid - you've included half the command line parameters for your `Scaffold-DbContext` command, too....

```
"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False'     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables DeviceParameterWithDevice -Context DPWDContext  -OutputDir Models -Force"
```

You need to change it to just this:

```
"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False"
```

Comment: Sorry when I cut and pasted the connection string file, it got corrupted in the question post above. The actual connection string is exactly as you listed it (I placed one under the other and confirmed exactly the same). The error that was reported happens with this connection string (ignore the one above)

Comment: I edited the original post with the correct ConnectionString (as mentioned it was always corect, just a cut and paste error - trying to edid out my actual SQL Server name and Catalog). Would still appreciate any comments on this post. Thanks